# Exoplayer video loading speed

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm looking to implement exoplayer in my project. I have successfully implemented it, but the loading time of video is slow. how to implement or to achieve speed loading of the video in exoplayer? just like tiktok does it - immediately loads the video and starts playing

Comment: Improve your server speed , I think the problem would be either server speed or internet speed

Comment: @ManoharReddy Thanks for an immediate response, i don't think it is an internet speed issue but then also after increasing speed I will try again, I think exoplayer having the issue of initial load of video and then playing, any other solution like tiktok uses immediate lading of video.

Comment: @akash did you init and setting up player in adapter or fragment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code

It's make buffer time small So,you can load video more speedily.

```
//Minimum Video you want to buffer while Playing
private int MIN_BUFFER_DURATION = 2000;
//Max Video you want to buffer during PlayBack
private int MAX_BUFFER_DURATION = 5000;
//Min Video you want to buffer before start Playing it
private int MIN_PLAYBACK_START_BUFFER = 1500;
//Min video You want to buffer when user resumes video
private int MIN_PLAYBACK_RESUME_BUFFER = 2000;

LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
.setAllocator(new DefaultAllocator(true, 16))
.setBufferDurationsMs(MIN_BUFFER_DURATION,
MAX_BUFFER_DURATION,
MIN_PLAYBACK_START_BUFFER,
MIN_PLAYBACK_RESUME_BUFFER)
.setTargetBufferBytes(-1)
.setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(true).createDefaultLoadControl();

TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Comment: ,Thanks for the response, i will try it and let you know if any issue is there.

Comment: ,DefaultLoadControl.Builder giving error,can you please tell me the reason.

Comment: I have not got any error please add this dependencies - implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.1'

Comment: I have implemented your code it is working fine but initial load takes time, how to resolve that. By the way, I am going to accept your answer.Thanks.

Comment: make more lower buffer time if it is possible.

Comment: can you please tell me which buffer time.

Comment: MIN_BUFFER_DURATION & MIN_PLAYBACK_START_BUFFER make this lower and also try to make 0 if it will work but I am not sure.

Comment: Not working even if the minimun playback start buffer is 1 second

Comment: i try this but doesn't work